# AngularJS: Service in different file

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS following an organization inspired by ng-boilerplate. I create different Angular modules for the different parts of my site.

However, I want to create all common elements (services and directives) under the main module, while having them all be in separate source files.

This code works, but is the module in sessionService.js referencing the same module than app.js, or is it creating a new one with the same name?

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [...])
.config(...)
.controller(...);
```

**sessionService.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('SessionService', function() { ... });
```

Comment: Only declare it with the dependencies once, then just use `angular.module('myApp');`

Comment: since `app` is the module, simpler to just do `app.service('SessionService'...`. And yes...it would be creating a new module as written, overwriting original

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you call `angular.module('myApp', [])` multiple times on the same page, you will likely run into errors or conflicts. I never tried that.

However, if you already run `angular.module('myApp', [])` once. Then you can run `angular.module('myApp')` (note: without `[]`) to retrieve (refer to) the `myApp` module you defined earlier.

Comment: Bingo. Declaring a module without dependencies reopens it for further definitions.

Comment: How do I add new dependencies from the callees?

Answer (score 7):

in controller.js file :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['newService']);
```

in service.js :

```
angular.module('newService',[])

.service('someService',function(){

    return {
         // return something
         return null
         }
    }

});
```

Do not forget to include both the js files in your HTML:

```
<script src="controllers/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="services/service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Naming & namespacing is important in any project. Try:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['sessionService', ...])...;
```

sessionService.js:

```
angular.module('sessionService', [])
.service('SessionService', ...);
```

Notice that the module name is in lower camel case while the service object itself is upper camel case. This will help you avoid namespace clashing. Hope that helps.