# inject a service in a component from the diff file - Angularjs 1.6

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I need a help. I use Angularjs 1.6 and I want just simply to inject a service from diff file in a controller. Looks pretty easy, aha)
Before I read this:
[AngularJS: Service in different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820887/angularjs-service-in-different-file).
But it didn't work in my case.

My code looks next:

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['formService', 'formLogic'])
```

component.js

```
angular.module('formLogic',[])
.component('formLogic',{
    templateUrl: './templates/form-logic.html',
    controller: function ($scope, formService){

    }
});
```

service.js

```
angular.module('formService',[])
.service('FormService', function($http){

});
```

But I got this error: [Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=formServiceProvider%20%3C-%20formService)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A-ha) it seems I inject in a wrong module and I don't need upperCase for the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't give your modules the same name as your providers (don't name both your module and your component "formLogic").
- Add your "formService" module as a dependency on your "formLogic" module.
- You have called your service "FormService" and are trying to inject "formService" into your component controller. "formService" is not a service that you have defined, it's the name of your module.

Answer (score 0):

To inject `component` and `services` from different *module*. Can inject the `module`.

component.js

```
angular.module('anotherModule',[])
.component('formLogic',{
    templateUrl: './templates/form-logic.html',
    controller: function ($scope, formService){

    }
});
```

service.js

```
angular.module('anotherModule')
.service('formService', function($http){

});
```

so no can use `formService` and `formLogic` from `myApp` module

like:

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['anotherModule']) // injected `anotherModule` in `myApp` modele
```

mainController.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, formService) {
  // can access `formService` from here
});
```

**OR**

you can use same module like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.component('formLogic',{
   templateUrl: './templates/form-logic.html',
   controller: function ($scope, formService){
      // ...
   }
});

app.service('formService', function($http){
    //.....
 });

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, formService) {
    // can access `formService` from here
});
```